# Deploying with a Procfile to dokku interferes with 'dokku run'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku, procfile

I recently added the `dokku-shoreman` plugin and a `Procfile` so that my app runs both a worker *and* web process when I deploy. It looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

However, now I when I use `dokku run <app> <cmd>` such as `...rake db:migrate` **a server and worker start running instead**.

Currently the only way I know how to run the worker is with the `Procfile`. It's not a big issue to start it manually after I deploy - only I don't know how.

Though the ideal would still be to have the both the `Procfile` and `dokku run` working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2** Dokku now supports this http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/process-management/

**Update**: checkout [dokku-alt](https://github.com/dokku-alt/dokku-alt) (no longer maintained) first - it's what I've switched to instead.

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/181) with dokku.

This was a [temporary solution](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/181#issuecomment-23055572) detailed in the issue discussion that worked for me:

1. rename actual`Procfile` to `Procfile.real`
2. create a new `Procfile` with the following content:

   `web: bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.real`
3. add `gem 'foreman'` as a dep in `Gemfile`
4. run `bundle install`
5. commit `Procfile*` and `Gemfile*`
6. push

Comment: Any idea how to use this temporary solution for a non-Ruby app? I’m using Python and thus doesn’t have a `Gemfile` :/

Comment: I'm sorry but I really have no idea. The github issue discussion was only for a Rails app. I'd recommend posting a Python 'version' of this question on here with the appropriate tags or adding an issue here: https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues

Comment: be aware that dokku-alt project is no longer actively maintained

Comment: Dokku now supports Procfiles directly. Using shoreman or executing your Procfile via foreman manually isn't good practice, so please just use our normal Procfile support, as documented [here](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/process-management/).

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez thanks - I've added that as an update at the top of the answer.